# Where should libraries be copied to sites/all or sites/all/modules?

Tags: navigation, theming

I currently have it in both locations, but figure this is incorrect. The problem is, when I try to remove it from sites/all/modules the superfish module complains, and says that it's needed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in the `sites/all/libraries`. For your information you need to create that libraries folder.

[**UPDATED ANSWER**]

You need to install [Libraries Module](https://drupal.org/project/libraries) too in this location `sites/all/modules/libraries`(this is a module).

Where as what you created as folder in `sites/all/libraries` folder, you will copy third party js files etc. (example is that you need to copy for superfish module, a set of library files  superfish.js file in this place only(`sites/all/libraries/superfish`))

If you do all this things then there will be no issues.

Also remember to give permission for newly created libraries folder(`sites/all/libraries`).

Answer (score 2):

You must create a directory `libraries` inside `sites/all folder`.

Comment: Thanks @pown


I have extracted https://github.com/mehrpadin/Superfish-for-Drupal/archive/1.x.zip to sites/all/libraries/superfish
I have extracted http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/superfish-7.x-1.9.zip to sites/all/modules/superfish
I have extracted http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/libraries-7.x-2.1.zip to sites/all/modules/libraries

My superfish menu parent is set to Main menu, Menu depth is set to 2 and Path levels is set to 1.

However, the superfish menu in the sidebar is always the same, regardles of what level of the menu I am in :(